# IBM Bluemix Spark: Supplying python dependencies to spark-submit.sh

Tags: python, apache-spark, dependencies, ibm-cloud

I'm using Cloudant Python APIs in my [IBM Bluemix PySpark](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/apache-spark/) applications.

How to I supply the dependent packages to spark submit ? The `py-files` option to `spark-submit.sh` takes only `py, zip or egg` files and my package is in `tar.gz` and `whl` formats.

This is the link to the the Cloudant Python Client Library that i'm trying to use - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cloudant

The article [How to install dependencies for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43805382/how-to-install-import-dependencies-and-execute-a-python-file-in-bluemix) talks about the same topic but i would like to see an example of the requirements.txt, Procfile and manifest.yml files mentioned in the solution.

Comment: The article you linked to is about python cloud foundry apps, not about spark apps so unfortunately is not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use pip programatically from your python script, e.g.

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', '--user', 'cloudant'])
```

This worked for me:

**helloSpark.py**

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext

import pip
pip.main(['install', '--user', 'cloudant'])

from cloudant.client import Cloudant
client = Cloudant('username', 'password', account='account', connect=True)

# do some spark processing
def computeStatsForCollection(sc,countPerPartitions=100000,partitions=5):
    totalNumber = min( countPerPartitions * partitions, sys.maxsize)
    rdd = sc.parallelize( range(totalNumber),partitions)
    return (rdd.mean(), rdd.variance())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="Hello Spark")
    print("Hello Spark Demo. Compute the mean and variance of a collection")
    stats = computeStatsForCollection(sc);
    print(">>> Results: ")
    print(">>>>>>>Mean: " + str(stats[0]));
    print(">>>>>>>Variance: " + str(stats[1]));
    sc.stop()
```

**run.sh**

```
./spark-submit.sh --vcap ./vcap.json --deploy-mode cluster \
     --master https://169.54.219.20:8443 \
     --conf spark.service.spark_version=1.6
     helloSpark.py
```

**The stdout after running:**

```
$ cat stdout_1498114277669877424 
no extra config
load default config from : /usr/local/src/spark160master/spark/profile/batch/
Requirement already satisfied: cloudant in /gpfs/global_fs01/sym_shared/YPProdSpark/user/s9c8-cbcae60bfa1d3e-39ca506ba762/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.7.0 in /usr/local/src/bluemix_jupyter_bundle.v47/notebook/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cloudant)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/spark-160-ego-master/work/spark-driver-380d8ae7-4ddc-452e-bb29-1665375a348c/helloSpark.py", line 8, in <module>
    client = Cloudant('username', 'password', account='account', connect=True)
  File "/gpfs/fs01/user/s9c8-cbcae60bfa1d3e-39ca506ba762/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudant/client.py", line 443, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/gpfs/fs01/user/s9c8-cbcae60bfa1d3e-39ca506ba762/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudant/client.py", line 114, in connect
    self.session_login(self._user, self._auth_token)
  File "/gpfs/fs01/user/s9c8-cbcae60bfa1d3e-39ca506ba762/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudant/client.py", line 172, in session_login
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/src/bluemix_jupyter_bundle.v47/notebook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 840, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://account.cloudant.com/_session
```

Unfortunately, I didn't save the output the first time I ran the script which informed that it had installed Cloudant.  But here you can see that the Cloudant library is available and attempts to connect to a cluster using invalid credentials hence the 401 error returned by Cloudant.

You probably don't want to attempt to pip install every time you run the script, so you could try this:

```
try:
    import cloudant
except:
    import pip
    pip.main(['install', '--user', 'cloudant'])
```

This will attempt to load the Cloudant library.  If there is an error loading it (e.g. because it hasn't been installed yet), it will be installed with pip.

Comment: Your welcome.  Can you please upvote and accept the answer?